# Adding a Typeclass to Java enum - without simulacrum

Tags: java, scala, enums, typeclass, simulacrum

I am trying to convert a couple of Java enumerations values into another Java enumeration (the usage of Java enum over Scala Enumeration is due to legacy reasons - the enums are actually generated using JAXB).

Instead of a plain old pattern matching and having a map mapping one enumeration type to another, I figured writing a typeclass looks cleaner (also kinda cool).  When I use simulacrum to do this, it compiles and runs just great.  However, when I try to hand-code the typeclass myself, it throws a compilation error

```scala
[error] /Users/arun/IdeaProjects/AdvancedScala/src/main/scala/MultipleToSingleEnum.scala:32: value toEmail is not a member of TradeEnum
[error]     println (TradeEnum.CLEARED.toEmail)
```

The code for the Java enumerations are :

**Source enumerations**

```
public enum TradeEnum {
    CONFIRMED, CLEARED
}

public enum SeriesEnum {
    CREATED,DELETED
}
```

**Target enumeration**

```java
public enum EmailEnum {
    T_CONFIRMED, T_CLEARED, S_CREATED, S_DELETED
}
```

**Typeclass using Simulacrum (Works just fine !)**

```scala
import simulacrum._


@typeclass trait EmailEnumConvertibleSim[A]{
  def toEmailEnum(value:A):Option[EmailEnum]
}

object EmailEnumConvertibleSim{
  implicit val tradeToEmailEnum = new EmailEnumConvertibleSim[TradeEnum]{
    private val map=Map(
      TradeEnum.CLEARED -> EmailEnum.T_CLEARED,
      TradeEnum.CONFIRMED -> EmailEnum.T_CONFIRMED
    )
    override def toEmailEnum(value: TradeEnum): Option[EmailEnum] = map.get(value)
  }

  implicit val seriesToEmailEnum = new EmailEnumConvertibleSim[SeriesEnum]{
    private val map=Map(
      SeriesEnum.CREATED -> EmailEnum.S_CREATED,
      SeriesEnum.DELETED -> EmailEnum.S_DELETED
    )
    override def toEmailEnum(value: SeriesEnum): Option[EmailEnum] = map.get(value)
  }
}

import EmailEnumConvertibleSim.ops._

object MultipleToSingleEnumSim {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println (TradeEnum.CLEARED.toEmailEnum)
  }
}
```

**Hand-coded type class (Ops)**

```
trait EmailEnumConvertible[A]{
  def toEmailEnum(value:A):Option[EmailEnum]
}

object EmailEnumConvertible{
  implicit val tradeToEmailEnum = new EmailEnumConvertible[TradeEnum]{
    private val map=Map(
      TradeEnum.CLEARED -> EmailEnum.T_CLEARED,
      TradeEnum.CONFIRMED -> EmailEnum.T_CONFIRMED
    )
    override def toEmailEnum(value: TradeEnum): Option[EmailEnum] = map.get(value)
  }

}

object EmailEnumOps{
  implicit class EmailEnumOps[A] (value:A){
    def toEmail()(implicit emailConvertable:EmailEnumConvertible[A]):Option[EmailEnum]={
      emailConvertable.toEmailEnum(value)
    }
  }
}

import EmailEnumOps._

object MultipleToSingleEnum {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println (TradeEnum.CLEARED.toEmail) //ERROR IS REPORTED HERE !!
  }
}
```

Any light on the error message is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing things from the simulacrum code into your handwritten typeclass code.

Comment: thanks a lot @Jasper-M. That was a result of a refactor.  The error is still around.

Comment: Could this be the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863699/implicit-not-found-when-omitting-empty-argument-list ?

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem like it @Jasper-M.  I don't get the "implicit not found".  It's just that the function isn't found.  I can see that I am doing something silly.  I really appreciate you looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your implicit class and the object it's defined in are both called `EmailEnumOps`.

When you change the name of the object it works:

```
trait EmailEnumConvertible[A]{
  def toEmailEnum(value: A): Option[EmailEnum]
}

object EmailEnumConvertible{
  implicit val tradeToEmailEnum: EmailEnumConvertible[TradeEnum] = new EmailEnumConvertible[TradeEnum]{
    private val map = Map(
      TradeEnum.CLEARED -> EmailEnum.T_CLEARED,
      TradeEnum.CONFIRMED -> EmailEnum.T_CONFIRMED
    )
    override def toEmailEnum(value: TradeEnum): Option[EmailEnum] = map.get(value)
  }

}

object AnyOtherName{
  implicit class EmailEnumOps[A] (value: A){
    def toEmail()(implicit emailConvertable:EmailEnumConvertible[A]): Option[EmailEnum]={
      emailConvertable.toEmailEnum(value)
    }
  }
}

import AnyOtherName._

object MultipleToSingleEnum {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println (TradeEnum.CLEARED.toEmail) // No error :-)
  }
}
```

It looks like that when an object is defined in the current scope and then you import a member with the same name, the first object is still shadowing the imported member.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object A { def B(a: Int) = "foo" }
object B 
import A._
B(4)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:41: error: B.type does not take parameters
       B(4)
        ^
```

An implicit class `EmailEnumOps` is compiled into a class `EmailEnumOps` and an implicit def `EmailEnumOps`. So when you imported `EmailEnumOps._` that implicit def was shadowed by the object, and consequently `TradeEnum.CLEARED` could not be implicitly converted.

This behaviour is as specified in the [language specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html):

> Bindings of different kinds have a precedence defined on them:
>
> 1. Definitions and declarations that are local, inherited, or made
>      available by a package clause and also defined in the same compilation
>      unit as the reference, have highest precedence.
> 2. Explicit imports have
>      next highest precedence.
> 3. Wildcard imports have next highest
>      precedence.
> 4. Definitions made available by a package clause, but not
>      also defined in the same compilation unit as the reference, have
>      lowest precedence.

Comment: Wowwwww !!!! Makes me look more stupid that I originally expected. Thanks a ton !! Works just great.

Comment: "An implicit class EmailEnumOps is compiled into a class EmailEnumOps and an implicit def EmailEnumOps. So when you imported EmailEnumOps._ that implicit def was shadowed by the object, and consequently TradeEnum.CLEARED could not be implicitly converted." - Sweet !